# 1830 farm house - installing metal vertical siding over original clapboards

Tags: siding

The current siding consists of asbestos shingles over original clapboards.  I have removed a few with just a long armed transfer shovel.  I was curious to see what was under them. Yes I will dress properly to remove the rest ;-)

Questions:
1) Once the shingles are removed, can I put some sort of foam board over the clapboards and then wrap?  Will that be airtight "enough"?
2) I then install vertical furring then install the vertical metal siding.  Is that going to work?

What I want to prevent is having to remove the clapboards. But I will and then sheath in zip if need be if that's the best option.

I want to save money...

Answer (score 1):

The way you are considering is quite standard. Rigid foam sometimes has a vapor barrier so you may not want a second one as it can trap the moisture and cause problems. With your asbestos shingles try not to break them and that will further reduce your risk of exposure to fibers when combined with proper PPE.

Comment: Thanks yes that's key on the shingles.  If I'm on a windy day, I'm in a PPE, I spray the house with super soapy water, I use a tarp...do I really have to worry about handling them so carefully?  Seems like I can knock off a lot of them with a long arm/flat headed shovel.